# Angular on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am developing an angular app that shows fine on Chrome but does non work at all on IE. Is there a way to configure IE to correctly show the app or to change the app so to show fin on IE?[image: Rendering on IE]
While this is the image on Chrome:
[image: Rendering on Chrome]

Comment: What version of angular and what version of IE? What errors are thrown?

Comment: Seems Internet Explorer is in IE7 compatibility mode. Have a look at the small "7" in the bottom right corner. If you click it, you should be able to choose "edge" instead.

Comment: it supports IE till 9 check https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: If you are using IE8 or older you should load polyfill scripts.

Comment: If I set Edge instead of 7 the buttons show fine but I get an error while displaying the table and no table is shown:
TypeError: L'oggetto non supporta la proprietà o il metodo 'values' in code: var elements=Object.values($scope[button]);

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Alex3683 for the button, it all just boils down to configuring IE for using Edge instead of 7 compatibility. As for the table IE does not support Object.values so I found and used a manual implementation working everywhere:

```
function objectValues(obj) {
    var res = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            res.push(obj[i]);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```